# Android Fatal Exception Threads Hierarchy (please explain)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've run into an error about thread hierarchy.  I know where the issue is, but I don't understand threads enough to understand why this is happening to me.

I have this as my basic code:

```
public class CameraPage extends Activity implements ImageSaver.OnImageSavedListener {
    public int numPics = 0;
    public Timer gifTimer;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        gif_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countdownTimer = new CountDownTimer((seconds * 1000 + 500), 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // Do things
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    numPics = 0;
                    gifTimer = new Timer();
                    gifTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            numPics++;
                            if(numPics <= 5) {
                                Log.d("********", "Take a picture " + numPics);
                            } else {
                                gifTimer.cancel();
                                Log.d("********", "No More Pictures " + numPics);
                                setCameraSpace();
                            }
                        }
                    },0,500);
                }
            }.start();
         }  
    });
```

Then the method for `setCameraSpace()` is here.  None of what it does is important to the answer, except changing the visibility of any `View`.

```
public void setCameraSpace(){
    Log.d("***********", "Finish " + bitmapArray);

    if (icon_alert_int == 1) {
        icon_alert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        icon_alert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(gallery){
        gallery_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        gallery_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    camera_preview_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    countdown_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    picture_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    back_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    front_flash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    front_flash.setAlpha(0f);
    countdown_timer.setText("");
    camera_text.setText(pref_session_start_inp);

    if (pref_session_auto_live_view) {
        //Countdown until Live view reappears
        live_view_timer = new CountDownTimer((pref_session_auto_live_view_inp * 1000 + 50), 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                auto_live_view_text.setText("" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - 1));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                latest_picture_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                camera_preview_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                auto_live_view_text.setText(String.valueOf(pref_session_auto_live_view_inp));
                camera_text.setText(pref_session_start_inp);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

so, I'm unsure about threads and when one is started/ended and how to put things in different places.  I assume the UI elements in the `setCameraSpace()` are not in a different, data-type thread because it's in a `run()` ?

Anyways, I'm getting this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
Process: com.cleanercoding.cleanerphotobooth, PID: 14355
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5029)
at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12953)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12917)
at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:10850)
at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:7233)
at android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.java:1420)
at com.cleanercoding.cleanerphotobooth.CameraPage.setCameraSpace(CameraPage.java:1263)
at com.cleanercoding.cleanerphotobooth.CameraPage$6$2$1.run(CameraPage.java:552)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of `Timer` (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) it appears that the Timer object has its own thread in which it executes tasks sequentially. This means that the UI is accessed from the thread owned by the `Timer`, not the thread owned by the UI.

See http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html for information on how to communicate with the UI when using threads.